# Nested for loops optimization

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, optimization

Is there a way to optimize the code below:

```
  public BigDecimal calculate(Policy policy) {
    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    for (PolicyObject policyObject : policy.getPolicyObjects()) {
      for (PolicySubObject policySubObject : policyObject.getPolicySubObjects()) {
        for (Risk risk : policySubObject.getRisks()) {
          for (Rate rate : risk.getRates()) {
            // CompareTo returns -1 if BigDecimal is smaller then to compared Big decimal
            // 0 if equals and 1 if greater.
            if (policySubObject.getSumInsured().compareTo(rate.getRangeStart()) >= 0
                && policySubObject.getSumInsured().compareTo(rate.getRangeEnd()) < 0) {
              total = total.add(policySubObject.getSumInsured().multiply(rate.getPremiumRate()));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return total;
  }
```

4 nested loops all together with a condition look very disturbing. Ultimately there is a need to go over each rate to calculate the premium I couldn`t find a better way to do it.

Comment: So you are just concerned with the looks of your code. There's not actually a performance bottleneck here, right?

Comment: Wouldn't be Code Review a better place for this?

Comment: If you don't like the look of it, separate it into methods. For example, a `Rate getRateForSubPolicy(Risk risk, BigDecimal sumInsured)` to choose the correct rate for the sum insured. Then a loop to give you a sum for all the risks, then a method to give you a sum for all sub-policies.

Comment: Some performance gains could probably be found with a parallel stream. It would also help readability IMO

Comment: I don't know the context of your method but if the collections have a lot of objects the method could be slow. You would calculate the total every time that someone modifies the policy object and saves the total value in an instance variable of the policy object: in this way you are slower when you update the object than you ask the value. The real question is: is the value more requested or more updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no obvious solution here, If loops are necessary here there is no way to get rid of them.